# set php-fpm user and group to website's owner

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have a centos 6 server which using apache to connect php-fpm to run php site, i use user's home directory for the website root, for example /home/user1, . On the other hand, the php-fpm www.conf, the lines user and group i set to apache.

So, when the php write or create a file (e.g /home/user1/var/log/file), it will use apache:apache as owner. Then i need to run a command at /home/user1/var/log/ "chmod -R ug+s ." to make php to create a file as apache:user1 while user1 is group

So my question is, it is possible to set php-fpm to create file using the directory user owner (user1:user1) but not apache:apache

Answer (score 0):

You can use module suPHP in Apache to specific User permission to run PHP script. You can take a look at this article 
http://blog.secaserver.com/2012/02/linux-install-configure-apache-suphp/

Comment: suPHP seems end of life, do any other solutions exist

Comment: There are many options in the field, you can search for "suexec", "mod_ruid2" or "mod_php" and choose one that fit for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of www.conf, create site.conf files in your pool.d directory.

Then you can set a user for each site:

```
user  = myuser
group = $user
```

You can also do

```
site  = $pool
group = $pool
```

if your username is `site.example.com` (handy for devops).

But consider that you might need

```
site  = $pool
group = httpd
```

or

```
group = www-data
```

(on Debian) if you want your apache to read the files that the pool creates, e.g. image uploads, if you use least-privilege permissions.

Make sure your socket locations and permissions agree as well so apache can talk to php_fpm.